# Can Selenium WebDriver click on all combinations from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So basically I need to get all combinations of Department, Course, and Section from the UCLA bookstore site: http://shop.uclastore.com/courselistbuilder.aspx and then I need to choose the books and parse the resulting html page.

Rather than doing it manually (which would take forever), I was looking up other options to do it programmatically. One option I found is Selenium WebDriver which deals with browser automation. Looking at examples from SO I find that the Selenium WebDriver is a promising feature but I am not quite sure if it can be able to do what I need it to.

More or less in pseudocode format, here is my approach on how I am going to use selenium web driver

```
go to the site: http://shop.uclastore.com/courselistbuilder.aspx

for each_department in department:
    click on each_department
    for each_course in course:
        click on each_course
            for each_section in section:
                click on each_section
// After every department, course, and section has been chosen, we click choose books
click on choose books link

// Save the resulting html file
save next page as html file
```

I wanted to know if I can be able to do what I want using Selenium WebDriver. It would be helpful if someone could offer better pseudocode that would be tied more appropriately with Selenium WebDriver but I am mainly focused on if this functionality could be possible. I also wanted to mention that I am planning to use the Python API when using Selenium.

Comment: The short answer is yes. Selenium is very powerful and I've used it to do basically what you're doing at my school. I will write up a quick demo for you shortly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is there you should start (explanation below):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


url = "http://shop.uclastore.com/courselistbuilder.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

departments = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('clDeptSelectBox'))
for department in departments.options:
    # select department
    departments.select_by_value(department.get_attribute('value'))
    time.sleep(1)

    cources = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('clCourseSelectBox'))
    for cource in cources.options:
        # select course
        cources.select_by_value(cource.get_attribute('value'))
        time.sleep(1)

        sections = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('clSectionSelectBox'))
        for section in sections.options:
            print {'department': department.text,
                   'course': cource.text,
                   'section': section.text}

driver.close()
```

Prints:

```
{'department': u'AFRCST - AFRICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'201A', 'section': u'1 - LYDON'}
{'department': u'AFRKLA - AFRICAN LANGUAGES', 'course': u'1A', 'section': u'1 - TA'}
{'department': u'AFRKLA - AFRICAN LANGUAGES', 'course': u'150A', 'section': u'1 - FANTA, A.A.'}
{'department': u'AFROAM - AFRO-AMERICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'6', 'section': u'1 - STREETER, C.A.'}
{'department': u'AFROAM - AFRO-AMERICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'M10A', 'section': u'1 - LYDON, G.E.'}
{'department': u'AFROAM - AFRO-AMERICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'M102', 'section': u'1 - LEWIS, L.I.'}
{'department': u'AFROAM - AFRO-AMERICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'M103A', 'section': u'1 - PRICE, Z.F.'}
{'department': u'AFROAM - AFRO-AMERICAN STUDIES', 'course': u'M104A', 'section': u'1 - YARBOROUGH'}
...
```

The idea is to extensively use [`Select` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) that provides a nice API the `select/options` functionality. First, we are getting all departments, then iterating over the options and choose the next department in the loop. Then, after the small delay, we are getting the list of `courses` and `sections` in the same manner.

I've left for you a better handling of [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html) (`time.sleep()` really is not very reliable) and clicking on `Choose Books` button (well, German Petrov provided you with both).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I was going to add an example but ya beat me to it. +1 for the use of `Select`

Comment: Thank you so much alexce and @ZWiki for you advice. I never knew that Selenium was such a powerful tool.

Comment: I just had one more quick question. Do I need to have Firefox installed on my computer to make this work or can it work with Safari?

Comment: @user2548635 configuring safari with selenium would be a headache, believe me. Easier to start with Firefox - yes, install Firefox (NOTE: 31st version, not 32nd).

Answer (score 1):

You can click all options using ~ such code:

```
select_dept = driver.find_element_by_id('clDeptSelectBox')
for option_dept in select_dept.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    option_dept.click()
    #wait until course has options
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='clCourseSelectBox']//option"))
    select_course = driver.find_element_by_id('clCourseSelectBox')
    for option_course in select_course.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
         option_course.click()
         #wait until section has options
         ....
```

and the same for section select, then waiting for link to present and click:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'Choose Books')]"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(., 'Choose Books')]").click()
```