# How to write a python program that 'scrapes' the results from a website for all possible combinations chosen from the given drop down menus?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, regression

There is a website that claims to predict the approximate salary of an individual on the basis of the following criteria presented in the form of individual drop-down

1. Age : 5 options
2. Education : 3 Options
3. Sex : 3 Options
4. Work Experience : 4 Options
5. Nationality: 12 Options

On clicking the `Submit` button, the website gives a bunch of text as output on a new page with an estimate of the salary in numerals.

So, there are technically 5*3*3*4*12 = 2160 data points. I want to get that and arrange it in an excel sheet. Then I would run a regression algorithm to guess the function this website has used. This is what I am looking forward to achieve through this exercise. This is entirely for learning purposes since I'm keen on learning these tools.

But I don't know how to go about it? Any relevant tutorial, documentation, guide would help! I am programming in python and I'd love to use it to achieve this task!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you not able to email them and ask for the database? The worst that can happen is that they say "no"

Comment: Thank you @roganjosh! But the thing is that it is a website that is prejudiced and morally handicapped. Its motive is to invoke humour through reinvoking cultural stereotypes. This is also the reason I did not name the website.

Comment: So your models will suffer the same limitations using their data. Whether you get the data through asking for it or scraping, it's the same data.

Comment: @roganjosh Yes that's what I want! I want to know what twisted logic that website creator has applied, haha

Comment: Fair enough, I assume this work subverts something so scraping might be the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are uncomfortable asking them for database as *roganjosh* suggested :) use **Selenium.** Write in Python a script that controls Web Driver and repeatedly sends requests to all possible combinations. The script is pretty simple, just a nested loop for each type of parameter/drop down.

If you are sure that value of each type do not depend on each other, check what request is sent to the server. If it is simple URL encoded, like `age=...&sex=...&...,` then **Selenium is not needed**. Just generate such URLa for all possible combinations and call the server.

Comment: Asking for the data is just polite IMO. It's also the simplest solution. I don't think anyone should be uncomfortable with it.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for the suggestion. I'll employ it in future when I need this trick.

Comment: @roganjosh: people are different. I cannot say &quot;everyone should&quot;. But I like that you dont limit your answer to a pure technology question. That&#39;s why I upvoted your comment before writing my answer.

Comment: @mentallurg Thanks for the reference! I got a similar question on SE too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25747294/can-selenium-webdriver-click-on-all-combinations-from-drop-down-menu?rq=1